# How to get difference in days?

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to subtract two dates in `teradata`

I tried the following

```
SELECT id, person , DATE 'opendate' - DATE 'closedate' 
FROM myTable1
```

I got an error

```
Invalid DATE literal
```

Why would I have it
The sample dates that I have are

```
2003-12-22  2000-07-19
2011-02-04  2008-04-02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE '.....'` is only for DATE literals, if the datatype is already a DATE you don't need anything:

```
SELECT id, person , opendate - closedate 
FROM myTable1
```

Otherwise you have to CAST:

```
SELECT id, person , CAST(opendate AS DATE) - CAST(closedate AS DATE) 
FROM myTable1
```